# Gradle sync takes too long Firebase-core could not HEAD status code 409

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am building an Android app in Android Studio. Every time I `Sync Project with Gradle files`, it takes several minutes to successfully sync. In the bottom of my Android Studio I see the following line for a few minutes:

[image]

In the build output I see this:
[image]

When I click on one of these errors, I see this:

> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.4.2/firebase-core-11.4.2.pom'. Received status code 409 from server:
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ArtifactDependencyGraph.createDependencies(ArtifactDependencyGraph.java:563)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.getDependencies(ModelBuilder.java:588)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createUnitTestsJavaArtifact(ModelBuilder.java:503)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createVariant(ModelBuilder.java:427)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:339)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:194)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**Question:**
I don't want my Gradle to sync for a few minutes, it takes way too long. Before I had this problem Gradle could sync in like half a minute. Can somebody help me fix this problem?

**What did I try:**
I read various SO answers and tried them, which led to:
1) Updating SDK Tools:
- Google Repository: version 58
- Android SDK Tools: version 26.1.1
- Google Play services: version 49

2) Adding repositories in the project Gradle file, the project build.gradle now looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using Firebase core 11.4.2? Can you show your Gradle app code?
First of all I will suggest you to update your dependencies. Fabric to `1.25.1` ,  play services to `4.0.1` and any firebase dependency to the new version (16.0.0). You can check the right version on https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks! Updated the packages in project gradle and in my app gradle. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: Great, I moved it to an answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your dependencies. It looks that you have a really old `Firebase` version.

- Update Fabric to `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1`
- Update Play services to com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1
- Update Any Firebase dependency to the most updated one.

You can find the new Firebase dependencies and their last versions on:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android